# Predicting a chosen Mortgage Type using Azure Machine Learning

Tags: azure, machine-learning

My objective is to predict what Mortgage Type a person will take on, based on their age, using Azure Machine Learning.

Note that I have 220,000 rows of data. There are several different Mortgage types but Purchases, Remortgages and Buy to Lets dominate the data.
A typical cross section of data might be: -

- Age 20, Purchase
- Age 30, Purchase
- Age 30, Remortgage
- Age 40, Remortgage
- Age 55, Buy to Let
- Age 55, Equity Release

My Azure Machine Learning Experiment is shown below.
My Metadata Edits are to change the MortgageType column to a label and the Age to an Integer. I have also played around with making them categorical/non-categorical.

[image: Mortgage Types Experiment]

When I view the Evaluation results, I get the following. 
[image]

Does this mean that I can only really predict Buy to Lets and Purchases with a 60% confidence?
Am I doing this correctly and is there any other way of achieving my objective?

Comment: Did i understand correctly that you only have the age as training data?

Comment: Yes that's right (note that I'm really new to this kind of thing). Although I've just added a postcode sector (e.g. LE10 1) as another feature. I'm getting slightly better results.
I've also changed the algorithm to a Multiclass Decision Forest and added a sweep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plot shown by AzureML is called a confusion matrix. In your case, it should be interpreted as:

For each mortgage which was actually a Bridging mortgage, there is a 64.7% chance the model predicted a buy to let mortgage, a 17.6% chance a purchase mortgage, and a 17.6% chance a remortgage.

Your model only ever predicts a selected mortgage to be a buy to let, purchase or remortgage. This is probably because you are only using age as a feature which does not give a lot of information to the model. Consider adding additional features to your model in order to increase its predictive power.

Comment: Thanks for this. I've added a Postcode sector as another feature, added a Sweep and also replaced the algorithm with a Multiclass Decision Forest.
It's now it's based on Location and Age - I'm getting much better results (91% accuracy). I'll see if there are any more features I can add.